# how distanciate element css, html

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

```
 <label for="label_name">aome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" size="37" maxlength="50" style="vertical-align: middle;"><br />
```

I need to put  to right of the page. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Check for `float:right` for the item or `text-align:right` for the parent ....

Comment: Which element is supposed to be on the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it in a `<div>` with `float:right;`.
Here's an example:

```
<div style="float: right;">
     <label for="label_name">aome:</label>
     <input type="text" id="nome" size="37" maxlength="50" style="vertical-align: middle;">
     <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depents on the elements around it.

```
.classforlabel, .classforinput{  
    float:right;  
}
```

However, I may recommend you to put that label and input inside a parent, and add the css above to that parent

Answer (score -1):

Put your elements in a div  with align right

```
    <div align='right'>
<label for="label_name">aome:</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" size="37" maxlength="50" style="vertical-align: middle;"><br />
```

Comment: `align` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.